# s3fs "could not determine how to establish security credentials"

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, filesystems, amazon-s3, s3fs

I'm trying to use s3fs to mount an S3 bucket on to a standard AWS Amazon Linux AMI (with all the necessary dependencies installed). However when following [this tutorial](http://wordpress-tips4all.blogspot.in/2014/07/wordpress-uploads-to-amazon-s3-using-s3fs.html) when I run: `s3fs mybucketname -o allow_other myfolder` or variations thereof, I get a response of:

> s3fs: could not determine how to establish security credentials

I've tried:

- creating passwd-s3fs in the etc folder, with the format: accessID:secretAccessKey
- creating .passwd-s3fs in the home folder
- setting AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment
  variables
- Opening up permissions on passwd-s3fs as far as possible (it's become more secure [since this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96229/how-to-install-and-setup-s3fs-on-os-x-lion))
- Giving the IAM user associated with this Access Key Administrator Access
- Successfully connecting via a local client with the same Access & Secret Access Key details
- Generally double checking everything for typos etc

I've a feeling I'm doing something dumb AWS side (I'm totally new to AWS), is there something specific I need to apply to the S3 bucket Permissions, Policy etc? This is driving me mad, help much appreciated!

Comment: It's unlikely to be anything in IAM, bucket policy, etc... sounds like an issue on the local machine.  You could try using `strace` to observe the system calls `s3fs` is making when you invoke it, and probably discover something useful from that.

Comment: The error "could not determine how to establish security credentials" occurs when the access key and password are not available. Maybe check the file permissions on .passwd-s3fs?

Comment: Hey man you got any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I found the best way to resolve this was to use the `-o iam_role` option to pass the name of the instance role in, plus if you're not in the us-east-1 region, you may also need to specify the `url` and `endpoint` options.

E.g.

```sh
s3fs mybucketname -o allow_other myfolder -o iam_role=$iam_role_name -o endpoint=${aws_region} -o url=https://s3-${aws_region}
```

(This is the command I used to mount an S3 bucket to an ECS container host instance, so an EC2 instance deployed as part of a cluster)

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is old, I also had the problem so I figure I would post the solution that worked for me in case another person has the same issue.

```
sudo apt purge s3fs -y
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install s3fs -y
```

In the current users home directory, create a txt file with the name .passwd-s3fs with your IAM credentials as such:

key:secret

i.e

> kjewndkjsn8387:emkwlmskld8/knsdknjnsjnsdk

```
# 1. use a text editor to add your key:secret & save the file
vim ~/.passwd-s3fs
# set permissions of .passwd-s3fs to 0400
sudo chmod 0400 ~/.passwd-s3fs
# mount drive s3fs /the_remote_path as /local_path
# i.e 
s3fs my_bucket:/the_remote_path /local_path
```

Answer (score 1):

This topic might be old but i ran into the same issue. The answer of Aslan and many other pages are "correct" but still did not work for me. I first did deinstall, update and upgrade like Aslan suggested, but I had to take care NOT to use any sudo commands. I strictly used:

```
nano ~/.passwd-s3fs
```

Like Aslan said, entered only

AccesskeyID:SecretAccessKey

i.e.

> kjewndkdui8374:emkwlmduiwj7/knsdknjnsjwkid

Then

```
chmod 0400 ~/.passwd-s3fs
s3fs bucket-name target-name
```

Took me like 2 hours to figure this out....hope i can help anyone to shorten this time.